# Argument of \@fileswith@pti@ns has an extra } when usepackage ifthen, changepage, ifoddpage

Tags: errors

When I use `\usepackage{ifthen}` or/and `\usepackage{changepage}` or/and `\usepackage{ifoddpage}`.

Error message:

```
&#8203;! Argument of \@fileswith@pti@ns has an extra }.<inserted text>\par \usepackage{

! Paragraph ended before \@fileswith@pti@ns was complete.<to be read again>\par \usepackage{
```

Minimal code:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,oneside,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[landscape,left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm]
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\begin{document}
abc
\end{document}
```

Comment: You simply forgot `{geometry}` in `\usepackage[landscape,left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}`. That is, you have `\usepackage[landscape,left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm]` but probably want to add `{geometry}` after that (or a similar package). Once I add this, the code runs through on my updated TeXLive 2019 installation.

Comment: @epR8GaYuh For the future: it's better to put error messages in a `code` block rather than a quotation block. The `code` block respects linebreaks, the quotation doesn't.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I do not think, that is will help other people in the future and the solution was trivial (forgot to add package name :)).

Comment: Sorry Dr. Manuel, but being a newbie to LaTeX, this has *definitively* helped me! Sure, I understand the policy on StackExchange and sure, it can be regarded off-topic. But it *did* help other people :) Greetings, Dr. Matthijs